# RecyclerView.OnScrollListener and ScrollingView : I am unable to create logic for scroll end

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have been reading *Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 2nd edition* for Android Development and I have been tasked with a challenge to "do something" when the scroller hits the end.

***Note:*** *Before describing the problem, I would like to say that I am not delegating homework to you. I have attempted the problem and shall provide my efforts here for reference*

---

Here is the complete picture:

To start with, here are the constraints:

- The implementation has to be with a `RecyclerView`
- Because I am supporting API level 16 as minimum, I have to implement `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` for scrolling event handling
- So I cannot use a `ScrollView` or any other alternative

Okay. The problem is simple - The RecyclerView is suppose to populate a grid of Views and these views are required to be updated with new content as the user scrolls way down to the bottom.
I have implemented `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and here is the code snippet:

```
private class PhotoScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener{

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
            //When the scrolled distance equals the extent of it, we need to load a new page
            Log.d("ScrollExtent", "dy=" + dy + "computeVerticalScrollRange()=" + mPhotoRecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange());

            if(dy == mPhotoRecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange()){
                //Reload the model object; Increment the page that needs to be retrieved
                mPageNo++;
                new FetchItemsTask().execute();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState){
            //STUB FOR NOW
        }
    }
```

This code is wrong as in the dy and `computeVerticalScrollRange()` differ in meaning and therefore this is a blunder.
I couldn't find what units these scroll methods return the offset and range in anywhere. It isn't documented on Android Reference either. There are other associated methods like, `computeVerticalScrollExtent()`, `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` but I am unable to find any way to check if *the scroller has reached the end*

Could anyone throw some light on working of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mPhotoRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            int lastPosition = gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            // reach bottom
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && lastPosition + 1 == mItems.size()) {
                new FetchItemsTask().execute();
                // updateUI: append new gallery item, you can refer to CriminalIntent
                // or simply use setAdapter() although it will lose previous page's data
                updateUI();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading = true;


recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }


        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            if (loading) {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;

                        Log.v(TAG, " Reached Last Item");

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```